# Load content in Div through rest and load page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using rest to get some data and populate two divs with the content I am getting. This rest ajax call is on index.html.

These divs I am populating with content from the rest call are on page1.html which I am loading using the document.on ready inside the  index.html at the end of the page.

The problem I am facing is sometimes when index.html loads, the divs are populated and sometimes they are not. I have to refresh the page for the divs to be populated. Any ideas or help will be appreciated. It may be code order or maybe I have to load the content on the success of the call?

```
    <!--check if ID is passed-->
    if ($.isNumeric(id)) {
        formPath = "forms/EditForm.html";
        getItemDetails(id);
    $("#form").load(formPath);
}


<!--make rest call-->
function getItemDetails(itemID) {
    console.log(itemID);
    var url = siteURL;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = data.d.results;
            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                step1AcknowledgementValue = item.Acknowledgement;
            });

            //**Populate Request Data**
            //Request#
            $("#requestNumberSpan").html(requestNumber);
            //Step1
            $('#step1Acknowledgement').html(step1AcknowledgementValue);
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: code added. thanks a lot in advance